# How to run same webdriver script in two different nodes in grid

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to run same script in two different nodes at the same time, how its possible?

Currently i am able to run one script in one node only.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't care about what's running in a specific node, the grid is managing it. I guess you are trying to run the same script for different browsers (probably, having configured the nodes for them). Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385052/selenium-grid-on-multiple-browsers-should-each-test-case-have-separate-class-fo/14648596#14648596). Here I explain a way to run tests in parallel for different browsers. The test code is (and should be) always the same.

Comment: i have created 2 nodes (one mac and other win 8)
i want to run same script on both machine at same time from hub.
i am using java-webdriver

Comment: The hub receives and manages all the requests to run some WebDriver code. According to WebDriver's capabilities, the hub will forward the request to a proper node. What you have to do is to initialize your instances of WebDriver with the desired capabilities (that should match some nodes' configurations) and enable the tests in parallel. Again, have a look at the answer that I mentioned above.